# How to list the connections of the port forwarded by firewalld?

Tags: linux, firewalld, netstat

I have forwarded a port using firewalld, and everything is functioning properly. However, the 'netstat' and 'ss' commands do not display the port opened by firewalld, nor do they show the connections. Since the forwarding is handled at the kernel level, 'netstat' and 'ss' won't reveal the connections or port status. I would like to know how to list the connections and check if the port is open without relying on 'nmap.' I would appreciate it if you could explain this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the point of view of the general networking stack, there is no local connection involved so no associated socket (so `ss` won't report anything), and as routing requires no associated state, it doesn't have to be known and isn't.

But to do NAT, such state must be memorized so all further packets get translated (including reply packets being "un-translated") the same. This is done by [*Netfilter*](https://www.netfilter.org/) and its *conntrack* facility in charge of tracking such connection states. *conntrack* is part of *Netfilter* and is the facility used by both *iptables* and *nftables*: whatever the backend in use by *firewalld* NAT is always tracked by *conntrack*.

The `conntrack` command (which in most Linux distributions, is usually made available with either the `conntrack-tools` package or the `conntrack` package) can query the (in-kernel memory) *conntrack* table. With an adequate filter: [`--dst-nat`](https://manpages.debian.org/conntrack/conntrack.8#g,) , it will display only connections which underwent a DNAT transformation: entries where the reply source is different from the query destination.

To display all such tracked connections currently in use (run as *root*):

```
conntrack -L --dst-nat
```

To monitor events about their state changes:

```
conntrack -E --dst-nat
```

---

This command can't display the rules creating such transformations since they are not themselves part of the *conntrack* state, but define the future behavior for such state. These rules are part of the firewall rules in chains hooking as NAT. Depending on *firewalld*'s backend (*iptables* or *nftables*), the result of this command done on a default setup:

```
firewall-cmd --add-forward-port=port=5555:proto=tcp:toport=6666:toaddr=10.3.3.2
```

Could be seen

- with *iptables* backend in a chain in the nat table:

  ```shell
  # iptables -t nat -S | grep -w 5555
  -A PRE_public_allow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5555 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.3.3.2:6666
  ```
- with *nftables* backend likewise with a chain with a similar name in the *inet firewalld* table, called from a base chain hooking with the nat type:

  ```shell
  # nft list chain inet firewalld nat_PRE_public_allow
  table inet firewalld {
    chain nat_PRE_public_allow {
        meta nfproto ipv4 tcp dport 5555 dnat ip to 10.3.3.2:6666
    }
  }
  ```

The fact that it's actually "opened" would be more difficult to check: one should just trust *firewalld* to have done what's needed for this. The current implementation of *firewalld* does this in a generic way by querying the *conntrack* facility:

- with *iptables* backend, this is done by adding the DNAT state to allowed states in each built-in chain also having DROP rules. So this will appear (together with other allowed states) as:

  ```
  -A <built-in> -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED,DNAT -j ACCEPT
  ```
- Usually with *nftables* backend, this is done by using  in each base chain that would also contain *drop* rules:

  ```
  ct status dnat accept
  ```

Both cases do the same: if the packet (along other possibilities) underwent a DNAT transformation (which can only have happened as result of the ruleset and thus of what is defined in *firewalld*), then accept it. Without having to duplicate again which specific port was allowed.

Older *firewalld* versions might have used *firewall marks* instead of *conntrack*'s state to act as memory to do the same.